# How to self join with nulls postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, self-join

I want to show the names of the customers along with the names of those who referred them. I thought I was on the right track but the result is messed up. I tried conditions `ReferredBy NOT NULL` in `WHERE` clause, `ReferredBy NOT NULL` in `ON` clause - no luck.
I would appreciate any help!
[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/895f60)

```
CREATE TABLE Customers(
          Id int NOT NULL,
          Name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
          ReferredBy int  REFERENCES Customers(Id),
          PRIMARY KEY (Id)
);

INSERT INTO Customers VALUES
(11, 'Peter', 22),
(22, 'Ariel', NULL),
(33, 'Tom', 11);
```

My approach:

```
 SELECT c.Id, c.Name, c.ReferredBy, n.Name as ReferredBy_name
 FROM Customers c
 LEFT JOIN Customers n
 ON c.Id = n.ReferredBy
```

Desired Output:

[image]

Comment: Sample data and desired results is helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `JOIN` conditions have the tables inverted:

```
SELECT c.Id, c.Name, c.ReferredBy, n.Name as ReferredBy_name
FROM Customers c LEFT JOIN
     Customers n
     ON n.Id = c.ReferredBy ;
```

Comment: Unbelievable! Thank you!